# is CellID used in AGPS even if no simcard is inserted in the phone?

Tags: gps, location, smartphone, android-gps

In smartphones AGPS is used. For example, in android, network provider uses  (AGPS, CellID, WiFi MACID)

**I have the following questions:**

- Is CellID used even when there is no sim card inserted?
- Is there a way to view the source code to see how location is
  calculated?

Thanks.